# Coverting user from anonymous firebase, but won't refresh screen flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication, flutter-layout

I have setup the convert user code below:
When I enter an email and password and click register, firebase makes the change but the screen won't go to the ProfileScreen, it just stays on loading. Once I hot restart the app, it shows the correct page.

```
  //create User object based on firebase user
  User _userFromFirebaseUser(FirebaseUser user){
    return user != null ? User(uid: user.uid, email: user.email) : null;
  }

  //convert users from anonymous
  Future convertUserWIthEmail(String email, String password) async {
    final currentUser = await _auth.currentUser();

    final credential = EmailAuthProvider.getCredential(email: email, password: password);
    await currentUser.linkWithCredential(credential);
    return _userFromFirebaseUser(currentUser);
  }
```

**PROFILE SCREEN WRAPPER**

```
class ProfileWrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  static const String id = 'profile_wrapper';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final user = Provider.of<User>(context);

    if (user.email != null){
      return ProfileScreen();
    } else {
      return ProfileRegister();
    }

  }
}
```

**IMPLEMENTATION IN PROFILE_REGISTER PAGE - *RoundedButton is a custom class***

```
    RoundedButton(
                                title: 'Register',
                                colour: Colors.white,
                                textColour: kMainColour,
                                onPressed: () async {
                                  if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                                    setState(() {
                                      loading = true;
                                    });
                                    dynamic result = await _authNew
                                        .convertUserWIthEmail(
                                        email, password);
                                    if (result == null) {
                                      setState(() {
                                        loading = false;
                                        error =
                                        'Please enter a valid email and password';
                                        print('ERROR HAPPENED');
                                      });
                                      _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(
                                          SnackBar(
                                            backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                                            content: new Text(error,
                                              style: kErrorMessageTextStyle,
                                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
                                            duration: new Duration(seconds: 3),
                                          )
                                      );
                                    }
//                                  setState(() {
//                                    showSpinner = true;
//                                  });

                                  }
                                }),
```

Answer (score 0):

Just move your `setState` before the `if` condition. That happens because you are not telling Flutter to update your UI after `_authNew.convertUserWIthEmail(` and only calling `setState` when an error happens (thus, removing the loading as well).

You want to remove the remove the loading state whether there is an error or success, so, basically:

```
 if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                                    setState(() {
                                      loading = true;
                                    });
                                    dynamic result = await _authNew
                                        .convertUserWIthEmail(
                                        email, password);
                                      setState(() {
                                        loading = false;
                                      });
                                    if (result == null) {
                                       error = 'Please enter a valid email and password';
                                        print('ERROR HAPPENED');
                                      _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(
                                          SnackBar(
                                            backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                                            content: new Text(error,
                                              style: kErrorMessageTextStyle,
                                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
                                            duration: new Duration(seconds: 3),
                                          )
                                      );
                                    }
```

Comment: That didn't solve it, it just got rid of the loading screen. The wrapper controls which screen to show.

Comment: Problem is the user.email is null until a hot refresh, even if I go to another page in the app and go back to the profile page, user.email is still null.